# Nested Activities and history in gwt activities and places

Tags: gwt

I have an application designed as follows.
It is a travel claim reimbursement app. It has two tabs:

1. My Claims : shows all reimbursement claims made so far
2. My Account: showing my details

It has number of claims on the Left and when selected displays Entries on the Right.

I have made the following Views.

- `AppView`: for Entire App which has tab panel and tabs
- `MyAccountsView`: for contents under MyAccount Tab.
- `MyClaims View`: for contents under Myclaims Tab. This has two panels. The one in left loads with the claims. The right is empty till a claim is selected to view.
- `SelectedClaimView`: for panel on the right hand side,which displays the claimentries of selected claim..

Each view has a correponding place and activity.

These are the following requirements which I am getting difficulty while creating my application:

When I click on claim on left hand panel the right hand panel must show claim entries within selectedClaimView. When I click another claim the list must be populated by contents of that claim. I also want history support for this claim selection.

I am facing following problems while designing:

1. How to add nested activities. e.g. When I select MyClaimsTab all claims must load up in left panel. On Selection of claim the claim entries must load in right panel via selected claims view. However calling an activity and changing the place stops the calling activity.
2. Also Both the activities in both tabs must run simultaneosly and history must be maintained between tab switches. This is something I dont know how to do and would appreciate suggestions.

Comment: “history must be maintained between tab switches” What does it mean? What do you expect the back button to do after changing tab?

Comment: When I switch tabs and press back button it must show the previous tab as active and the place token must change accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirements are very simple, and so should be your design. You need only two activities and two views: AccountView and ClaimsView.

You need a simple widget - a FlowPanel with two labels styled as tabs - as your navigation menu. You put this widget at the top of both views, and attach a ClickHandler to the label which corresponds to the other view - i.e. in AccountView attach a handler to Claims label, which triggers presenter.goTo(new ClaimsTab(""). Claims label should be styled as a pressed tab in ClaimsView, and Account label  - in AccountView. This takes care of navigation: no special activity is necessary for it.

AccountView is simple: navigation widget at the top, details below. For ClaimsView use a LayoutPanel split into three layers: top layer for navigation widget, left layer for claims, and right layer for details. Let's assume you use a Tree for claims, and a FlowPanel ("claimDetailsPanel") wrapped in a ScrollPanel for claim details.

Your ClaimsView should have a flag "initialized" (with a getter and setter). When a user comes to a ClaimsTab place, you start your ClaimsActivity. This activity gets a reference to ClaimsView. It checks if ClaimsView is initialized. If not, it loads the list of claims and populates the Claims Tree. When you build your tree, set each claim as a user object for each TreeItem. Then set the initialized flag to true.

You attach a selection handler to your tree that calls presenter.goTo(new ClaimsTab(selectedClaim.getId().toString()));

This will send the user back to the same tab, but with a new URL token - you will see #ClaimsTab:123 token if selected claim had id=123.  There will be no flickering on the screen, because the ClaimsView has been already built and remains visible.

Now you will have a new ClaimsActivity running. This activity notices that (a) there is a token that needs to be processed, and (b) there is no need to load claims and populate the claims tree because the view is initialized. Your activity should parse the token (convert it to a claim id), load the details of this claim, and give this information to the ClaimsView to populate the claimDetailsPanel (which you should clear first because it can have content of the previous claim).

One little detail. A user can bookmark any claim. So if your ClaimsActivity builds the claims tree, it should check for a token. A bookmarked page will have a token, so the activity should tell the view which tree item to select.

This is it: two views, two activities. Nothing nested.

Answer (score 0):

The [Slotted](https://code.google.com/p/slotted) framework allows you to easy do this. (Disclaimer: I wrote [Slotted](https://code.google.com/p/slotted)).  Let me describe a simple way to do what you are wanting.  You define your main AppPlace like this:

```
public class AppPlace extends SlottedPlace {
    public static final Slot TabsSlot = new Slot(new AppPlace(), new MyClaimsPlace());

    @Override public Slot getParentSlot() {
        return SlottedController.RootSlot;
    }

    @Override public Slot[] getChildSlots() {
        return new Slot[] {TabsSlot};
    }
}
```

This tells Slotted framework that your AppPlace has a Slot which can contain another Activity inside the current View.

In the AppActivity you will need to extend SlottedPlace and override this method:

```
@Override public void setChildSlotDisplay(Slot slot) {
    slot.setDisplay(tabsSlotWidget);
}
```

tabsSlotWidget will be a SimplePanel or SimpleLayoutPanel that will be used as the container for the new activity.  It is possible to have two Slots in the AppPlace, and you can also have slots inside the MyClaimsPlace.  There is a SlottedTab widget which provides similar functionality as TabPanel, but allows each tab to be an Activity.

Other than the changes described above, Activities work the same as GWT A&P.  You can also run an existing A&P site inside Slotted and only upgrade the Activities that need nesting.

1. This allows multiple Activities to be started at the same time, which normal GWT A&P doesn't allow.  If you call a Place, that is at the same level in the Activity, it will only replace that Activity and still keep the rest of the hierarchy in place.
2. Slotted will handle the history for the entire hierarchy, so no matter how many levels/breadth of nesting, the history token will allow it to be recreated.

Answer (score -1):

I hope I can point you in the right direction.

1. There are an endless amount of ways of implementing logic. I would recommend reading up on the command design pattern (google it you will find good resources)
2. If you mean history by browser history see [DevGuide](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsHistory).
   If you mean simply remember what the user chose options. Then simple write your own class which remembers it, this might also help you with 1..